# Best way to find all the previous event IDs by customer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on this problem that looks fairly straightforward. The data looks like:

[image]

For example current event ID for customer id is abc. Now, I need to find all the eventId for all the customers in a list format such that the first event ID is recorded and then next until the latest event ID.

The approach I used for 1 customer is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
data.to_dict()
{'customerid': {0: 233, 1: 250, 2: 233, 3: 250, 4: 233},
 'eventid': {0: 'abc', 1: 'bcd', 2: 'edc', 3: 'abl', 4: 'cdl'},
 'date': {0: '2019-12-10',
  1: '2019-12-08',
  2: '2008-12-10',
  3: '2019-12-01',
  4: '2001-12-10'},
 'previouseventid': {0: 'edc', 1: 'abl', 2: 'cdl', 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan}}
```

```
    customerid  eventid date    previouseventid
0   233 abc 2019-12-10  edc
1   250 bcd 2019-12-08  abl
2   233 edc 2008-12-10  cdl
3   250 abl 2019-12-01  
4   233 cdl 2001-12-10
```

```
temp = [cust_233['eventid'][0]]

for i in range(len(cust_233['previouseventid'])-1):
    if pd.isna(cust_233['previouseventid'][i]) == False:
        # print(cust_233['previouseventid'][i])
        temp.append(cust_233['previouseventid'][i])
    else:
        # print('now exiting')
        break
```

I feel like my approach is little clunky and has lot of code. How do I solve the problem efficiently for all the customers?

**Updated:**

The output I need is list. 
The expected output for customer 233 is an list ['cdl', 'edc', 'abc'] and for customer 250 is ['abl', 'bcd']

Comment: please format the code correctly. Also, the expected output is not clear

Comment: I updated the code and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.sort_values('date', ascending=True).groupby('customerid', sort=False)['eventid'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
customerid
233    [cdl, edc, abc]
250         [abl, bcd]
Name: eventid, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Groupby then shifting should work:

```
# First, make sure your data is sorted from oldest to newest
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)

# Get previous event through groupby operation
df['prev_id'] = df.groupby('customerid')['eventid'].shift(1)
```

If you want a list for each customer:

```
# create a dictionary with stored values – keys are customer id
prev_events_dict = df.groupby('customerid')['eventid'].apply(list).to_dict()
# map dict to dataframe
df['list_of_prev_id'] = df['customerid'].map(prev_events_dict)
```

Comment: You should finish with a df.sort_index(), to get back to the original form. Nice formula btw!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am looking to get a list of eventids for each customer in a list format.

Comment: Gotya. Added to my answer @JdBaba

Comment: Goo point @oppressionslayer – assuming the previous index is meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list like this:

```
df['previouseventid'] = df['customerid'].map(df.groupby('customerid')['eventid'].apply(list))
```

output:

```
   customerid eventid        date  previouseventid
0         233     abc  2019-12-10  [abc, edc, cdl]
1         250     bcd  2019-12-08       [bcd, abl]
2         233     edc  2008-12-10  [abc, edc, cdl]
3         250     abl  2019-12-01       [bcd, abl]
4         233     cdl  2001-12-10  [abc, edc, cdl]
```

df.groupby('customerid')['eventid'].apply(list)  will get you just the lists

```
df.groupby('customerid')['eventid'].apply(list)                                                                                                                                     

customerid
233    [abc, edc, cdl]
250         [bcd, abl]
Name: eventid, dtype: object
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I appeciate it.